# Passing function inside a stateless component is not working

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, components, stateless

I try to use a function inside of my stateless component. But it's not working properly.

```js
const selectedColor = function ({color}) {
    switch (color) {
        case 'green':
            return styles.green;
            break;
        case 'blue':
            return styles.blue;
            break;
        case 'red':
            return styles.red;
            break;
        default:
            Alert.alert("Undefined Color!");
    }
}
const LightBulb = ({isLit, lightColor}) => {



    return (
        <View
            style={[isLit ? selectedColor(lightColor) : styles.green, {alignSelf: 'stretch'}]}>
            <Text>{isLit ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</Text>
        </View>
    );


}
```

---

When `isLit` is true, `selectedColor(lightColor)` should be triggered. And once it is triggered, even `lightColor` is one of greed,red, or blue, it goes to `Alert`. Can you explain why this happens? And could someone give me a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a few changes in your code and it's working now, Demo is here.

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/smiling-carrot

or here is the code which is running, You just need to pass your color in your function and it will be shown.

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const App =()=>{
  const [isLit, setIsLit] = useState(true)
const selectedColor = (color)=> {
  console.log('color:', color)
    switch (color) {
        case 'green':
            return {backgroundColor: 'green'};
        case 'blue':
            return {backgroundColor: 'blue'};
        case 'red':
            return {backgroundColor: 'red'};
        default:
            Alert.alert("Undefined Color!");
    }
}
    return (
        <View
            style={[isLit ? selectedColor('red') : {backgroundColor: 'green'}, {alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 200}]}>
            <Text>{isLit ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</Text>
        </View>
    );

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It should be stateless. Does `userState` make it stateful?

Comment: @FerdaNahitFIDANCI you can pass any value according to your need on "isLit", I am just passing value for demonstration.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When I remove {} of {color}, it works.